# Form init and field init events do not work in parsley.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js, validating

Here's a simple example: http://codepen.io/spacejaguar/pen/KrvqNW

html:

```
<form data-parsley-validate>
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" required>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="validate">

  <p><small>This is a simplistic example, good to start from when giving examples of use of Parsley</small></p>
</form>
```

and JS

```
$(function () {
    $('form').parsley()
    .on('form:init', function() {
        console.log('Form init', arguments);
    })
    .on('field:init', function() {
        console.log('Field init', arguments);
    })
    .on('form:validate', function() {
        console.log('Form validate', arguments);
    })
    .on('form:submit', function() {
        return false; // Don't submit form for this demo
    });
});
```

It seems that **form:init** or **field:init**  callback functions are not called at all, while any other one works just fine. What do i do wrong? Or maybe it's a bug?

[EDIT]
I looked into source code and did some debugging stuff, it seems that init event is triggered before any listener has been attached. Creating parsley instance looks alike:

- $.fn.parsley is called
  -- new ParsleyFactory is created, calls init fn
  --- ParsleyFactory.prototype.init validates config etc. and calls bind fn
  ---- ParsleyFactory.prototype.bind decides which constructor to create (ParsleyForm, ParsleyField or ParsleyMultiple)
  ----- new ParsleyForm is called and returns instance
  ----  ParsleyFactory.prototype.bind **triggers init event** and returns instance
  --- ParsleyFactory.prototype.init returns instance
  -- ParsleyFactory constructor returns instance
- $.fn.parsley returns instance
- **.on('field:init', function() { ... }) is being bound**

Comment: Interesting. So `$.Parsley.on('form:init')` will work, but that's the only way to catch the event. It would indeed probably be best to trigger the event just after the initialization (say using `setTimeout`). Feel like writing a PR?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm unable to do so in the near future, but I'll give it a try later.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and thanks to your research on the event triggering I found a solution. Just bind the event handler to the `window.Parsley` object and it will work just fine.

For example:

```
window.Parsley.on('form:init', () => console.log('form:init'))
```

Comment: Yes, it solves the issue somehow, but keep in mind that this way you bind `form:init` globally and it will be called for each parsley instance.

Comment: That is true. In this case I only had one form. To be honest the event binding/event emitting in parsley is not really clear to me.